# Is the phrase "Those machines down" incomplete in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The text:

"Destroy HADES with the Master Override - Those machines down, it's finally time to put an end to the Corruption and take down HADES. Walk over to the panicking program and give it a good old jab with your Master Override Lance, and it's job done."

is an excerpt fro this link:

"https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-11-24-horizon-zero-dawn-walkthrough-guide-tips-4932?page=22"

I can't make sense of "Those machines down" of connect it to anything the way it is. If there was a word: "bring" or "are" alike in:

"Bring those machines down"

Or

"Those machines are down"

then a could wrap my head around it

is this phrase incomplete?

Comment: It's gamer talk, which does not have obey any rules of grammar. It probably means 'once those machines are down".

Comment: It's ***very peculiar phrasing***. The specific text ***Those machines down*** is effectively "short for" ***Once / Now that those machines are down** (taken out of action)*. But that's  rather "formal / literary" phrasing, which doesn't sit at all well with extremely colloquial ***give it a good old jab***. Maybe it's as @MichaelHarvey implies - gamers aren't necessarily competent writers of English. Plus they may often get their "linguistic registers" mixed up when there's added confusion coming from the "other-worldly" fantasy world within which they play.

Answer (score 1):

We can introduce the topic of a completed action or event with 'Once' and a verb phrase, e.g. 'those machines are down', 'the monster was dead'. We can omit 'once' and the verb, so 'The machines down, we can [do something]', or 'The monster dead, we were able to escape'.

Comment: Or it might be "with those machines down", following on from the previous episode in which you had to take down some machines.

Comment: I would think of it as short for 'those machines being down" or "now tthat thsoe machines are down"

Comment: “Now that those machines are down”